# IdentityServer4 IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, identityserver4

hi i trying to learn identity server 4 . i tried a simple project with api client id4 api-gateway .... but now i try the same project with docker container. my client app at the beginning must redirect to identity server login page but throw error

```
SocketException: Connection refused
System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: Connection refused (identityserver4:9001)
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://identityserver4:9001/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://identityserver4:9001/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
```

Identiti server client configuration in Config.cs

```
new Client
                {
                     ClientId = "razorClient",
                     ClientName = "RAZOR Client App",
                     AllowedGrantTypes= GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                     RequirePkce = false,
                     AllowRememberConsent = false,
                     RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                     {
                         "http://clientapp:5001/signin-oidc"
                     },
                     PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                     {
                         "http://clientapp:5001/signout-callback-oidc"
                     },
                     ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                     {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                     },
                     AllowedScopes = new List<string>()
                     {
                         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                         "MYAPI"

                     },
                     AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
                     
                }
```

IdentityServer program.cs

```
using IdentityServer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    //.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
    .AddTestUsers(Config.TestUsers)
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{


    app.UseHttpsRedirection();


}



app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});

app.Run();
```

client app program.cs

```
using ClientApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>(); 


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{

    options.Authority = "http://identityserver4:9001";
    options.MetadataAddress = "http://identityserver4:9001/.well-known/openid-configuration";


    //options.Authority = "http://localhost:9001";
    //options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:9001/.well-known/openid-configuration";

    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientId = "razorClient";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("MYAPI");

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

});


builder.Services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

docker-compose.override

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  identityserver4:
    container_name: identityserver4
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      
    ports:
      - "9001:80"


  clientapp:
    container_name: clientapp
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    depends_on:
      - identityserver4


  apiresource:
    container_name: apiresource
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
```

and this is the test project [repo](https://github.com/rooz90s/IdentityServerTest2)

EDIT: i edited the question based on simple project contains api and client and identityserver4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change all urls based on the ip address of the computer where docker is running. e.g.:

Client app:

```
options.Authority = "http://192.168.8.202:9001";
options.MetadataAddress = "http://192.168.8.202:9001/.well-known/openid-configuration";
```

IdentityServer config:

```
RedirectUris = new List<string>()
{
    "http://192.168.8.202:5001/signin-oidc"
},
PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
{
    "http://192.168.8.202:5001/signout-callback-oidc"
},
```

You can find your computer's ip address with `ipconfig` command in windows cmd or `ifconfig` in linux terminal.

Comment: i tried you solution but still i am getting the same error IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://identityserver4:9001/.well-known/openid-configuration'. OR first Connection refused

Comment: i think its about the networking ... be cause i tested the client without authorization to http call the identity server to read http://identityserver4:80/,well-known/openid-configuration and it works. the problem is that the authority is handle between containers inside the docker so with that address its ok but the identityserver UI need to handle by local host but the configuration is set based on container inter communication i think.

Comment: I suggest to try setting all urls based on your machine's ip address. e.g. `options.Authority = "http://192.168.8.202:9001";` and identity server config `"http://192.168.8.202:5001/signin-oidc"`

Comment: thanks for response. how to find that .. in inspect info the IP is set to 172.19.0.2. do you mean this ip address. how can i find that ip address in that mask. also it may be helpful to check my new question .. it is same but more specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036131/identity-server-4-on-docker-issue

Comment: Command `ipconfig` in windows cmd or `ifconfig` in linux terminal.

Comment: ahhh ok ok .. now i got what you mean... let me try... good point

Comment: DUDE thanks you very very much. you saved me .. its almost a week. that works like a charm. please post it as answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I edited original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a container communication issue. The Exception occurs when the OpenId handler tries to parse the response from the discovery to an object. It's probably because the expected json is not being returned.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
```

Ensure you reach the discovery endpoint from your web app. You are using the url of your service available from the docker host (localhost):

```
options.Authority = "http://localhost:3300";
options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:3300/.well-known/openid-configuration";
```

But you need to configure a network to communicate both containers and use the service name instead of localhost:

```
gewebapp:
  container_name: gewebapp
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  depends_on:
    - identityserver
  ports:
    - "3002:80"
    - "3003:443"
  networks:
    - mynet

identityserver:
  container_name: identityserver
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  ports:
    - "3300:80"
  networks:
    - mynet
```

And in the handler configuration:

```
options.Authority = "http://identityserver:3300";
options.MetadataAddress = "http://identityserver:3300/.well-known/openid-configuration";
```

Comment: hi thank you for response ... i tried what you said but still i have the same problem. i created small sample in this repo https://github.com/rooz90s/IdentityServerTest2 if you want check. after IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; its for sure that it cant read the openid configuration. even when the id4 service is down it throws the same message so it sems it cant find the identityserver at all.

Comment: @alpha78 i am now sure its about the container communication. why need to create custom defined bridge network ? the services are in the same docker compose. i test two service api call each other in the same docker compose and its handled by http://servicea:80/api/call without custom defined bridge. so my first mistake is  the addressing but now for identity server i get browser response DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when i set it to http://identitserver4:80

Comment: Maybe you don't need to configure de network in your compose, ok, but at first, you was traying to reach IdentityServer from your web app by using localhost. As I see it, That was a communication problem. Now you get a DNS resolution problem, another communication problem.

Comment: Docker compose creates the network, but  the container name you are using is `identityserver`, and the host you are trying to resolve is `identityserver4`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: itried also with identityserver and got the same result. actually identityserver4 is the container_name .... i figure out from the same docker compose i can call serviceA from ServiceB using http://servicea:80/api/call .. so i tried do the same as identityserver4:80. when is use the port 9001 like local host it throe connection refused and consequently follow by IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from

Comment: FYI this happen when client must redirect to identityserver login page. but when i use the port 80 as http://identityserver4:80 the client does not throw error and redirect to the http://identityserver4/connect/ but error with dial tcp: lookup identityserver on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host. this happen for both identityserver4 name and identityserver. ( NOW I FIX THE NAME FOR BOTH CONTAINER AND DEFINED CONTAINER NAME AS identity4 ) i working on smaller sample project thats why .. i will edit the question